# Cut the end and start from a Extruded SVG in Three.js

Tags: svg, three.js

I have a problem with extruding a svg in three.js.
this is the result of my code.
[image]

But I must cut the end and beginning of this model like the next image.

[image]

How can I do this after the extruding of the svg?

Answer (score 0):

Clipping allows part of the geometry to be cut out of the render.
Made a codepen here: https://codepen.io/cdeep/pen/LYjGNxR

```js
renderer.localClippingEnabled = true;

const clippingPlane1 = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 1, -1, 0 ), 1 );
const clippingPlane2 = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( -1, -1, 0 ), 1 );

const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  clippingPlanes: [clippingPlane1, clippingPlane2],
});
```

The examples section has more complex examples for clipping.
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clipping#webgl_clipping_intersection

Official documentation for `clippingPlanes`:
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.clippingPlanes